# How do I free a linked list in C and why does it work well without freeing the list?

Tags: c, list, malloc, valgrind, free

```
typedef struct Element Element;
struct Element{
    char chaine[2048];
    struct Element *next;
};

typedef struct Liste Liste;
struct Liste{
    int taille;
    struct Element *premier;
};

Liste listeinit(void){
    Liste *L = malloc(sizeof(Liste));
    L->taille = 0;
    L->premier = NULL;
    return *L;
}


void inseretete(Liste *L,char *x){
    Element *ele = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    if (ele == NULL){
        printf("Erreur en attribuant la memoire");
        return;
    }
    int cpt = 0;
    while (x[cpt]!='\0'){
        ele->chaine[cpt]=x[cpt];
        cpt ++;
    }
    ele->chaine[cpt]='\0';
    ele->next = L->premier;
    L->premier = ele;
    L->taille ++;
}


void freeliste(Liste *L){
    while(L->premier != NULL){
      Element *a = L->premier;
      L->premier = L->premier->next;
      free(a);
    }
    free(L);
}
```

I'm trying to free a linked list and it kind of works when I remove the free(L) line but when it's there, it prints "double free or corrupt". How do I fix that ?

We tried to remove and add it.

Comment: This is an incomplete example. The `createliste` is missing, and it likely didn't use `malloc`. You can use `free(L)` only if `L` was allocated on the heap.

Comment: You're probably freeing the `Liste` object in the caller. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Haven't you missed one `}` after `struct Element *premier;`?

Comment: @MSalters I eddited my post. But I stille don't understand, I'm sorry...

Comment: In your `listeinit` function, you're leaking the pointer to the allocated memory; you're not returning a pointer, you're returning a copy of the struct that memory points to.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Okay. May I ask if you have an easier solution for this please ?

Answer (score 0):

This ...

> ```
> Liste listeinit(void){
>     Liste *L = malloc(sizeof(Liste));
>     L->taille = 0;
>     L->premier = NULL;
>     return *L;
> }
> ```

... is wrong.  You are allocating memory dynamically for a `Liste`, but then returning *a copy* of that by value, and leaking the allocated memory.  Moreover, if you record the copy in space that is not itself dynamically allocated then you cannot free that space via `free()`.

Presumably, you wanted to return the pointer instead of a copy of the allocated space:

```
Liste *listeinit(void) {
    Liste *L = malloc(sizeof(Liste));
    L->taille = 0;
    L->premier = NULL;
    return L;
}
```

The caller would of course need to be adjusted to match.  When you were ready, you would pass the pointer on to `freeliste()`.

---

Alternatively, you could provide a function for initializing a `Liste` without allocating memory for it.  That would then be paired with a function for releasing the nodes that did not also attempt to free the `Liste` itself.  For example,

```
void listeinit(Liste *L){
    L->taille = 0;
    L->premier = NULL;
}

void freelistenodes(Liste *L) {
    while (L->premier != NULL) {
      Element *a = L->premier;
      L->premier = L->premier->next;
      free(a);
    }
}

void useliste() {
    Liste my_liste;

    listeinit(&my_liste);

    // do something with my_liste ...

    freelistenodes(&my_liste);
}
```